# Polymer codelab build material design inconsitency

Tags: polymer

I was following the codelab for material design (http://io2014codelabs.appspot.com/static/codelabs/polymer-build-mobile/#1) and I have a question that I cannot find answer to:

Why the font size is applied to the '.card' elements "manually" (iterating over the elements and setting the style) - this leads to a bug - when you change the font size it is applied to all existing items but when you create a new one it does not have the style applied and thus looks weird until you re-adjust the font size from the menu.

I have tried to bind it directly (i.e. style="font-size: {{fontSize}}px" but this does not work. It works on other elements but not in the secondary template element.

Any insights on this please? 
a) why the binding does not work?
b) how would one fix the 'bug'?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's the step in question: http://io2014codelabs.appspot.com/static/codelabs/polymer-build-mobile/#7

It's under the "Add a slider that changes the font size" sub-section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained [here](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#nested-scoping-rules). Basically, when you *don't* use a [named scope](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#single-template-instances), you lose access to ancestor template scopes.

The fix involves switching to a named scope and rewriting all bindings inside to use it:

```
<template repeat="{{datum in data}}" >
  <div center horizontal layout class="item" data-done="{{datum.done}}">
    <paper-checkbox checked="{{datum.done}}" on-change="{{datum.dataChanged}}"></paper-checkbox>
    <div flex class="card paper-shadow-top-z-2" style="font-size: {{fontSize}}px;">
      <p>{{datum.body}}</p>
      <paper-ripple class="fit recenteringTouch"></paper-ripple>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then the style binding works and you can delete `fontSizeChanged`.